# Security: is there a way to work in Debug with shared keychain groups w/o provision profile?

Tags: xcode, macos

I have a project which uses Security framework to work with Keychain and I need to test shared keychain groups, but as soon as I add keychain group to entitlements the project does not build.

I see [Swift keychain and provisioning profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355630/swift-keychain-and-provisioning-profiles), but it does not help for my case.

I have "Sign to Run Locally" signing certificate for Debug, but still no help.

Any ideas? Is there any setting to activate I missed?